# Transitioning from recordset to dataset

Tags: vb.net, vb6, dataset, recordset

I'm working on a project of trying to update from VB6 to VS.Net.. I'm very iffy and lost on how the recordset is supposed to be functioning in this piece of code, so of course that doesn't help with trying to do the same action with a dataset. I would be most grateful if someone could explain this and advise on how to proceed implementing with a dataset. It's the "Recordset!" portion that is really throwing me off.

```
Private Sub cmdTemp_Click()
  Dim sz As String
  If txtTemp >= 0 Then
    sz = "Update ProdSheet set Temp = " & txtTemp & " "
    sz = sz & "Where Prod like '" & adoSchedList.Recordset!Prod & "' "
    adoLoggedDBExecute sz
  Else
    MsgBox "Enter a Value for the Temperature you wish to update"
  End If 
End Sub
```

this is my attempt in VS 2017

```
Private Sub CmdTemp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmdTemp.Click
  Dim sz As String
  With TxtTemp
    If IsNumeric(.Text) Then
      If Val(.Text) >= 0 Then
        sz = "Update ProdSheet set Temp = " & TxtCheck.Text & " "
        sz = sz & "Where Prod =  @!Prod "
        LoggedDBExecute(conn, sz)
        MsgBox("Worked")
      End If
    Else
      MsgBox("Please enter a numeric value!")
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a variable named `adoSchedList` somewhere else in the code? It will be an instance of ~some~ class. That, and the `LIKE` comparison, appear to have been lost in the translation.

Comment: We don't know what LoggedDBExecute is doing, but in VB.Net, you would use `WHERE Prod = @Prod` or `WHERE Prod = ?` and then supply the parameter information to your command object.  It's not clear from your code if you are still using ADODB in the VB.Net version.

Comment: adoShedule list is a variable that I dim as new dataset and then fill using a sql statement, I am not using ADODB, but I was trying to leave the variable names as close to the original as possible. sorry for the unclearness